# How to print lines from a file that contain six or less asterisks in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, filter

If I want to print out lines from a file containing various and random lines with asterisks sprinkled throughout them (a.k.a they could be anywhere, beginning, end, spaced out, etc.) How can I most concisely print out only the lines that contain 6 or less (total) asterisks? I've tried everything, but can't find a neat solution.

```
******   
a*b*c*.****   
abc  
1234** **~}{      *  

(*)  
   ****  abc****
```

(Note: Some of the lines above end with spaces)

From the above, sample file, I'd want all lines to print out, including the blank one (line 5), with the exception of the last line, because it has a total of 8 asterisks.

Everything I've tried so far doesn't seem to be able to tally up the total number of asterisks per line- I have tried using sed to remove all characters minus the asterisks, and then using grep to print the eligible lines, but then this approach is getting too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -v '\(\*[^*]*\)\{7\}' file.txt
```

The `\*[^*]*` bit in parentheses means "an asterisk, followed by any number of non-asterisk characters", and `\{7\}` means seven of this pattern. The `-v` means it filters out matching lines instead of printing them.

You can also use the `egrep` command or `grep -E` to not have to use as many backslashes:

```
egrep -v '(\*[^*]*){7}' file.txt
# or
grep -vE '(\*[^*]*){7}' file.txt
```

Comment: Wow! That totally worked. Thank-you, you are amazing. No one I knew could figure this out, and so quickly....do you have any suggestions for how I can get better quickly at awk.grep.sed outside of the usual channels? (i.e. man, unix.com)